# Optimizing page load and speed

Tags: html, dom

Morning all... so I am noticing something on my site: www.summerlawnsinc.com

HTML5 CSS3, pretty standard responsive template.
What I am noticing is that when the page first renders, the main Logo is stretched, and shifted far left as it loads, then displayed properly after a second or so.

I have tried several things to alleviate this, using various sizes and trying to optimize the image and such...

However, I have a feeling this may be due to the plethora of scripts I am loading on the page, from my chat, googl analytics, some facebook pixel tracking and such...

I am trying to see what I can do to help speed up the page load and not have this "hiccup" on the page...

I have used a few online tools to get some guidance, but they dont seem to properly give me specifics as to what will help...

Just looking for some tips and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**style must load first instead your js, probably your js takes time to load before the your style:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
```

- remove all js from your html. ( bad practice )
- do a indetation for your html js and css.
- minimize your css and js for that you can use grunt.

**try all this and let me know if you archive what you want. good look!!!**

updated, you are getting this errors too:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) (program):1 'webkitURL' is deprecated. Please use 'URL'
>   instead.
>   http://www.summerlawnsinc.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://www.summerlawnsinc.com/css/skell.css Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I have minified CSS, JS, and optimized as many images as I could. I have tried to use the "async" property in the javascipt files, as well as try to load the CSS first... but the "flash" of the image loading and getting all stretched out still happens... I am wondering if it has somethign to do with the HTML5UP template I am using.

Comment: I did... I fixed the two missing resources.